# Insert a Hypertext link in an Excel textbox

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, textbox

I have a sheet with a textbox, created with VBA :

```
With Worksheets(1)
  .Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 0, 100, 100).TextFrame.Characters.Text = _
      "Some text here" & LinkHere & "Maybe more text here"
```

I would like to insert a link in the text of the textbox , but i can't find vba code to do that.
The link i would precisely add is a `"mailto:"` link.

**Edit**

Actually, a textbox cannot have usable links, so my second question is : what object can i use to have well formated text and a link into it ?

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. What's the problem/question?

Comment: Keep in mind if it's a box you can type into, you cant make it a functional hyperlink.

Comment: I did not find how to insert that link using vba. And that is right, link is not usable. Is there a better object i can use ?

Comment: You can use a Label, and then style it to look like a link, and then add some code on the click event to open the link, but that's about as close as you can get using VBA - https://www.computergaga.com/blog/add-a-hyperlink-to-a-userform-excel-vba/

Comment: A `TextBox` contains plain text. A hyperlink is not that. If you're in a 32-bit host, you can use a `RichTextBox` with formatted RTF text, which presumably (no idea) supports hyperlinks - but that won't work on a 64-bit host, so I wouldn't recommend it. Why not keep your UI nice & simple, with controls that are actually supported and known to work in all hosts regardless of bitness? If you want a fancypants UI, don't do it in VBA.

Comment: I will ditribute my excel, then i suppose i cannot use ```RichTextBox```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay then, i will use label.

Here is the best i found :

```
With Worksheets(1)
 Dim l:l as Shape = .Shapes.AddLabel(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 0, 100, 100)
 l.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "link text here"
 .Hyperlinks.Add l, "mailto:someone@example.com"
```

The *hypertext link is set to the whole label here*, then i must place it precisely as an overlay of the text.